# C# - Determining if a Stored Procedure exists

Tags: c#, sql-server, stored-procedures, dbcontext, exists

I've written a `DbContext` extension to try and determine if a stored procedure exists within its associated database.

```
    public static bool StoredProcedureExists(this DbContext input, string name)
    {
        int exists = input.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(string.Format("SELECT TOP 1 * FROM [sys].[objects] WHERE [type_desc] = 'SQL_STORED_PROCEDURE' AND [name] = '{0}';", name));

        //return true; // if it exists, else false
    }
```

The problem is: regardless of whether the stored procedure `name` exists or not, my `exists` variable (returned from `ExecSqlCommand`) always contains '-1'.  So I am unable to determine if the stored procedure is in the database or not.

Executing the generated query in the SQL Server Management Studio works as expected, returning one row if the stored procedure exists and no rows if if does not.

Does anyone have any ideas on how to achieve this (programmatically determine if a stored procedure exists with a database) ?

Thanks
Rob

Comment: I would strongly recommend to use the **more focused** catalog views and avoid `sys.objects` whenever possible. Your query will be easier to read and understand if you use `SELECT .. FROM sys.procedures WHERE ....`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thanks for the help...  In the end I got it to work as follows:

```
    public static bool StoredProcedureExists(this DbContext input, string name)
    {
        var query = input.Database.SqlQuery(
            typeof(int), 
            string.Format("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [sys].[objects] WHERE [type_desc] = 'SQL_STORED_PROCEDURE' AND [name] = '{0}';", name), 
            new object[] {});

        int exists = query.Cast<int>()
            .Single();

        return (exists > 0);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do a stored procedure, and send the procedure's name as a parameter to check if it exists

```
               SELECT [schema] = OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME([object_id]),
                       name
               FROM sys.procedures;
               WHERE name = @param_proc_name
```

and call that procedure from your code before your logic.

Comment: Thank you for the reply.  I'm trying to avoid having any dependencies.  I'm planning on keeping it as generic as possible for my base library.

Comment: i dont know if im correct here or not, but executesqlcommand wont help you here as it returns the result returned by the database after executing the command. since there is no output parameters nor a returned integer, this statement is behaving as expected. try an execute scalar command.